# Is there a way to hardcode connection string to RDLC?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I need to make report viewer that will handle reports localy. 
I got RDL files with querys. Is there a way to insert conenction string into
report's XML code so the report can get data from database directly? reports will
be display in MS reportViewer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="BIA">
      <DataSourceReference>BIA</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:DataSourceID>98fa74a9-d829-4196-be9d-49697ded5201</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="RelItems">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="RelItemID">
          <DataField>RelItemID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="SSISPackageName">
          <DataField>SSISPackageName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>BIA</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>select b.ID as RelItemID, SSISPName --+ '  ('+s.Name + ' -&gt; ' + d.Name + ')' 
as SSISPackageName
    from dbo.RelTypes_ProvTypes a
    inner join dbo.RelItems b on a.RelTypeID = b.RelTypeID
    inner join dbo.ObjItems s on b.ObjItemIDSource = s.ID and a.ObjTypeIDSource = s.ObjTypeID
    inner join dbo.ObjItems d on b.ObjItemIDDest = d.ID and a.ObjTypeIDDest = d.ObjTypeID
where SSISPName is not null
order by 2</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>

... and so on
```

This is RDL I have.
Any other tips or help is welcome, just need to make it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDL files contain query information that isn't stored in RDLC files as used the ReportViewer control. If you want to use your RDL file outside of SSRS in the ReportViewer then you can set the datasource property from code when running the report in local mode. That way you set the connection string to whatever you want when you build the datasource.

```
ReportViewer1.Reset()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = <yourfilepath>
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(<yourdatasource>)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

(obviously this snippet is VB)

Comment: Tnx on response...
The problem is that new reports can be added to app so I want to use sql inside reports. It's a big job to add all data set's with code every time new report is added.

I found that in datasource can be added connection string..
But could use help what I'm doing wrong.

<DataSource Name="xxx">
<rd:DataSourceID>98fa74a9-d829-4196-be9d-49697ded5201</rd:DataSourceID>
<DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
<ConnectString>...</ConnectString>
IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>

DB i'm trying to connect is MS SQL

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think what you want to do is possible with an RDLC file. The connection string element isn't used in an RDLC file which is why it is set to `/* Local Connection */`, which requires you to set the connection at the ReportViewer.LocalReport level.

Comment: I fear you are right... So there is no way I could read data from databese to report direct without any c# code in between?

Comment: I don't think so. That's one of the points of the differences between RDL and RDLC - the C stands for Client which gives you access to processing the report datasource locally. Sounds like you need to use RDL, just without SSRS, but you can't

Comment: Thank you on your time... I'm tired of digging for somethign that doesn't exists :)